react-vite Error: GET jsx file net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I'm aware this question has been asked a lot here, but I'm not too sure where to find a solution. I have a portfolio website that I keep receiving these two errors in the website's console:
First, this:
[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()], and then when I refresh, I see this:
[GET https://j-992.github.io/main.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)]
My portfolio website: https://j-992.github.io/portfolio/
My repo code: https://github.com/J-992/portfolio
Help?!
I'm using react and vite to create the site as it allows me to add 3D components. But I'm not sure why main.jsx isn't able to be accessed/found.
I've tried multiple solutions for hours but haven't been able to pinpoint what is actually causing the issue. I tried rearranging folder structures, changing package.json contents, changing index.html contents, and more... Moved main.jsx around, tried to change how it was being referenced in index.html, maybe I'm just overlooking an issue that's in fact really simple to fix?
Also just wanted to note, the website itself isn't fully done, however I just wanted to deploy it beforehand so I could iron out issues like this current one (and learn how to fix them if I come across them in the near future).
